# Anyone else having trouble with the User Token Generator for Instagram basic display testers?

Tags: instagram, facebook-opengraph, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

[I start here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeNFt.jpg)

Every time I click the 'generate' button I get a little popup that says

[Error!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckRh2.png)

Not sure how to get around this, or if the problem is even on my end.

I tried going into incognito in case cookies were messing things up however that did not help. I have also waited, as it suggests, but the problem is consistently happening no matter the test account both yesterday and today.

Any ideas?

Comment: Same, I retried by logging in to instagram already, copying the URL including the full query string. Nothing changes, it's just 429 error each time. The 'retry-after' header is saying "1", which should be 1 second. But it always ends with a 429.

Comment: I tried just mashing the refresh button on it, and it went through once. Then I have a url at developers.facebook.com/instagram/token_generator/oauth with a code in the query string. This is the code that is supposed to be exchanged for the token. However, the page just loads plain white. Then after trying to refresh it a bunch of times, including inside incognito, it was still white, then after a while it switched to the standard Meta "Sorry, something went wrong" page.

Comment: It's not just the token generator for me, I can't even get logged in connecting using a different auth system.

Comment: I know this isn't useful, but for some reason it just worked for me. I don't think I did anything differently. Sorry, but maybe keep trying?